# The YUI datatable with ajax

Tags: javascript, asp-classic, yui

I developed a asp page that is showing persons table(YUI datatable) and has search box. If the data is searched in search box, the datatable is updated with ajax postback.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Testing Datatable</title>
        <!--CSS file (default YUI Sam Skin) -->
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/datatable/assets/skins/sam/datatable.css">

        <!-- Dependencies -->
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/yahoo-dom-event/yahoo-dom-event.js"></script>
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/element/element-min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/datasource/datasource-min.js"></script>        
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.2.2/build/connection/connection-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <!-- Source files -->
        <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/2.9.0/build/datatable/datatable-min.js"></script>
        <style type="text/css">
            /* basic skin styles */
            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt table {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                font-family:arial;font-size:inherit;
                border-collapse:separate;*border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0; /* since ie6 and ie7 behave differently */
                border:0;
            }

            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt th,
            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt th a {
                font-weight:normal;
                text-decoration:none;
                color:#000; /* header text */
                vertical-align:bottom;
                background-color:#EEEEFF;
            }

            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt th {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                border:0;
                border-top: 1px Solid #CCCCCC; 
                border-bottom: 1px Solid #CCCCCC; 
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt tr.yui-dt-first td {
                border:0;  /* tbody top border  */
                border-bottom: 1px Solid #CCCCCC;
            }

            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt th .yui-dt-liner {
                white-space:nowrap;
                background-color:#EEEEFF;
            }

            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-coltarget {
                width: 5px;
            }

            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt td {
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                border:none;
                border-bottom: 1px Solid #CCCCCC;
                text-align:left;
            }

            /* sortable columns */
            .yui-skin-sam thead .yui-dt-sortable {
                cursor:pointer;
            }

            .yui-skin-sam th.yui-dt-asc,
            .yui-skin-sam th.yui-dt-desc {
                background:url(../../../../assets/skins/sam/sprite.png) repeat-x 0 -100px; /* sorted header gradient */
                background-color:#EEEEFF;
            }

            /* striping */
            .yui-skin-sam tr.yui-dt-even { background-color:#FFF; } /* white */
            .yui-skin-sam tr.yui-dt-odd { background-color:#F9F9F9; } /* light blue */
            .yui-skin-sam tr.yui-dt-even td.yui-dt-asc,
            .yui-skin-sam tr.yui-dt-even td.yui-dt-desc { background-color:#FFF; } /* light blue sorted */
            .yui-skin-sam tr.yui-dt-odd td.yui-dt-asc,
            .yui-skin-sam tr.yui-dt-odd td.yui-dt-desc { background-color:#F9F9F9; } /* dark blue sorted */

            /* disable striping in list mode */
            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-list tr.yui-dt-even { background-color:#FFF; } /* white */
            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-list tr.yui-dt-odd { background-color:#FFF; } /* white */
            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-list tr.yui-dt-even td.yui-dt-asc,
            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-list tr.yui-dt-even td.yui-dt-desc { background-color:#F9F9F9; } /* light blue sorted */
            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-list tr.yui-dt-odd td.yui-dt-asc,
            .yui-skin-sam .yui-dt-list tr.yui-dt-odd td.yui-dt-desc { background-color:#F9F9F9; } /* light blue sorted */

        </style>
    </head>
    <body class="yui-skin-sam">
        <input type="text" id="Search" /><input type="button" value="Search" onclick="myDataTable.AjaxSearch();" />
        <div id="PersonContainer">
        <table id="PersonTable">
            <tr>
                <td>Mg Mg</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Factory Worker</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Ko Ko</td>
                <td>21</td>
                <td>General Worker</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Aung Aung</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Office Staff</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Aung Ko</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>Office Staff</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Mg Aye</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Office Staff</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Min Aung</td>
                <td>25</td>
                <td>Office Staff</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">

            var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(YAHOO.util.Dom.get("PersonTable"));
            myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_HTMLTABLE;

            myDataSource.responseSchema = {
                fields: [
                    { key: "Name"},
                    { key: "Age" },
                    { key: "Occupation" }
                ]
            };

            var myColumnDefs = [
                { key: "Name", sortable:true},
                { key: "Age", sortable:true},
                { key: "Occupation", sortable:true}
            ];

            var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("PersonContainer", myColumnDefs, myDataSource);

            myDataTable.AjaxSearch = function(){
                var sUrl = "AjaxTest1.asp";
                var callback = {
                    success: function(o) {
                            if (window.DOMParser)
                                {
                                    parser = new DOMParser();
                                    xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString(o.responseText,"text/xml");
                                }
                                else // Internet Explorer
                                {
                                    xmlDoc = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
                                    xmlDoc.async="false";
                                    xmlDoc.loadXML(o.responseText); 
                                }

                                var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(xmlDoc);
                                myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_XML;
                                alert(o.responseText);

                                myDataSource.responseSchema = {
                                    resultNode: "person",
                                    fields: [
                                        { key: "Name"},
                                        { key: "Age" },
                                        { key: "Occupation" }
                                    ]
                                };

                                var myColumnDefs = [
                                    { key: "Name", sortable:true},
                                    { key: "Age", sortable:true},
                                    { key: "Occupation", sortable:true}
                                ];

                                var myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("PersonContainer", myColumnDefs, myDataSource);
                        },
                    failure: function(o) {
                        alert("AJAX doesn't work"); //FAILURE
                        }
                    } 

                var request = YAHOO.util.Connect.asyncRequest('POST', sUrl, callback);
            };          

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

That is return xml data:

```
<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<person><Name>Aung Aung</Name><Age>25</Age><Occupation>Developer</Occupation></person>
<person><Name>Mg Mg</Name><Age>20</Age><Occupation>Programmer</Occupation></person>
```

The return data is two rows. But the datatable showed one row. How can I do this to show return rows?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is related, but I have seen a few cases where if an ID was not provided, YUI just makes one up. In those scenarios we have seen missing rows due to it keying off of this Id. The first idea I would have would be to add a field or column def for Id and then include a unique Id in the returned XML data.